# Associate a domain name to a directory in Apache

Tags: apache, dns, ip, virtualhost, dedicated-server

I have an Ubuntu dedicated server, and I have 2 domain names. The first one is related to the directory '/var/www/' and the second one is too, I didn't know how to associate the second one to another directory like '/var/www/site2/'
Can you help me ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To host multiple domains on the same server with different directories of their own, you need to use the **VirtualHost** config directive. Inside each one you can specify their own set of configurations (by default the configuration file is stored at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
        <Directory /var/www/site1>
            Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName another-example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
        <Directory /var/www/site2>
            Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The first one lives in /var/www/site1 and has directory indexing turned off. The other is in /var/www/site2 and has directory indexing turned on. You can specify pretty much most configs to be virtualhost specific - ie, custom logging, use of modules such as php or perl, and ServerAlias, among much more. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost for more details.